# What is this plant that sometimes accompanies parsley?

Tags: herbs

I frequently buy bunches of flat-leaf parsley. Every now and then I find one or two stems of a different-looking plant included. Here is an image, with normal flat-leaf parsley on the left. I remember it having a grassy, plausibly parsley-like smell, but nothing strong.

Is this some variant of parsley, or a different plant altogether?

[image: Parsley and ?]

Comment: Does it smell like anything when you break a leaf?

Comment: Does it taste like parsley?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your mystery plant is....parsley.  [This question was asked and answered here.](https://ask.extension.org/questions/341846)
It appears that the best explanation is a leaf variant on the common cultivar "Italian Giant".  Having grown this cultivar in my home garden, I can attest to having personal experience with this leaf shape.  Chop it up and use it as you would the rest of the parsley.